# What is the difference between "Theology" and "Hashkafa" tags?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

What is the difference between [theology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theology) and [hashkafah-philosophy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashkafah-philosophy) tags?

They sound like the same tag.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [two](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/theology/info) tag [wikis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/hashkafah-philosophy/info). My view is that the former is needed specifically for questions about our understanding of God, while the latter is more general.